# How can I tell if an ARM9 development board/evaluation kit has support for hardware floating point operations

Tags: linux, arm, hardware, arm9

I'm browsing Farnell and Digikey for a devboard with an ARM9 processor, 128MB of RAM, hardware floating point support and Linux support.

All of the features are relatively easy to filter, apart from the hard float support.

I've searched through a lot of datasheets manually, but there is not a single instance where floating point support is mentioned, either as software emulated or provided by hardware.

How would I go about searching for such a board?

Comment: Software floating-point is available on anything, for obvious reasons. In terms of hardware, I suspect it's just that [virtually nothing has it](http://uk.farnell.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Search?catalogId=15001&langId=44&storeId=10151&categoryName=All%20Categories&selectedCategoryId=&gs=true&st=ARM9%20VFP).

Comment: Is there a reason you need an ancient processor?

Comment: @Notlikethat thank you for your input, you are helpful as usual.

Comment: @EOF project requirements :). The client will probably deploy our implementation to existing hardware. It's a bit weird from our POV as well, but hey, not our call to make.

Comment: more modern arms have a set of CPUID registers to indicate such things.  If the armv5t doesnt have this then you could try simply talking to the (floating point) coprocessor (execute an instruction) and if you get an abort, then there isnt a coprocessor there.

Comment: If it's a case of developing for existing hardware, rather than speccing a part for a new project, then it may also be worth scouting around to see if it's possible to dig up an ancient development board from back when ARM9 was a high-end application processor, rather than a microcontroller core (how times change!). Those are perhaps more likely to have the elusive FPU, and if one existed for the actual SoC you're deploying to, all the better. The downsides would be availability and the almost certain complete and utter lack of vendor support for a ~10-yead-old bit of dev kit.